# Regex to match list of numbers inside matching group

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regular expression, to match a list of numbers inside an html tag.

The tag is data-p="and the content is here".

Inside the content there is a list of numbers formatted like this:

```
[&quot;16834091899728893939&quot;,&quot;8871244709062187521&quot;,&quot;3716487480481705970&quot;,&quot;1266937738203421917&quot;]
```

I would like the regex to return the list of digits: [16834091899728893939, 8871244709062187521, 3716487480481705970, 1266937738203421917]

Is it possible to match a list inside an already matched group?

It is easy to match content of all data-p's tags from the whole page: "data-p="(.*?)"", but I cannot get the list f numbers from inside.

Is it possible to do al in one regex?

Thanks !

Full html below

```
data-p="%.@.null,null,null,null,null,null,[8,null,[&quot;oyo rooms gurgaon&quot;,[null,null,null,&quot;INR&quot;,[[2023,1,27],[2023,1,28],1,null,0],null,[],[],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[[[353,null,true],[]]],null,null,null,[],null,null,null,[],null,null,null,null,[],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[]],[null,[&quot;16834091899728893939&quot;,&quot;8871244709062187521&quot;,&quot;3716487480481705970&quot;,&quot;1266937738203421917&quot;],null,null,null,null,1,1,3,null,null,null,null,null,[],null,null,null,null,&quot;Gurugram, Haryana&quot;,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,&quot;oyo rooms gurgaon&quot;,null,[false]],0,null,null,0,null,false,null,null,false,null,null,null,null,null,[[[1],[3,[null,true]],[5,[null,true]],[4,[null,true]],[6],[7],[8]],false]],null,null,null,null,null,2]]"
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but this really seems like a bad fit for regular expressions.

Comment: ok, I am interested in other opinions too :)
how would you parse it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which regex engine you are using. For example, using the PCRE engine you can construct the following regex:

```
(?:data-p="[^"]*?\[|\G,)&quot;(\d+)&quot;
```

Here is the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/TV5SZ2/1).

This expression match a `&quot;(\d+)&quot;` string under two conditions: it should either be preceded by `data-p="[^"]*?\[` pattern, or it should be preceded by `\G,` pattern. The first pattern is obvious. The second one includes `\G` to match the position of the previous match. This disables matching the `&quot;(\d+)&quot;` after every comma. In the demo above it disables matching of the string `456` in the `other-tag`.